# Mean, Median, and Mode incorrect in c++ program

Tags: c++

Title says it. The program basically is supposed to do as follows; Ask someone who surveyed students how many they surveyed, enter the number of movies those students watched, then find the average, mean, and mode. It does use pointers, and dynamic arrays. Code is below, and help is appreciated. For input, I'm using 1-10, which gives me an average of 5.5, median of 6.5, and -1 for the mode.

**EDIT** Forgot to mention this, but it appears as if my logic is flawed here. If someone can point out why, that would be great...

**EDIT 2** Updated the code with a bubble sort, to help fix some of the issues I'm having. Here's the updated code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double calculateMean(int *, int);
double calculateMedian(int *, int);
int calculateMode(int *, int);
void bubbleSort(int *, int);

int main()
{
    int *nums;
    int num_students;
    char repeat = ' ';

    do
    {


        cout << "Enter in how many students were surveyed: ";
        cin >> num_students;


        while (num_students < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid number of students!\n";
            cout << "Enter in how many students were surveyed: ";
            cin >> num_students;
        }


        nums = new int[num_students];


        for (int count = 0; count < num_students; count++)
        {
            cout << "Number of movies say by Person #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> nums[count];

            while (nums[count] < 0)
            {
                cout << "Invalid number. Please enter in a positive number: ";
                cout << "\nNumber of movies say by Person #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
                cin >> nums[count];
            }

        }
        bubbleSort(nums, num_students);

        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

        cout << "\nThe mean is: ";
        cout << calculateMean(nums, num_students) << endl;

        cout << "\nThe median is: ";
        cout << calculateMedian(nums, num_students) << endl;

        cout << "\nThe mode is: ";
        cout << calculateMode(nums, num_students) << endl;

        delete[] nums;
        nums = 0;

        cout << "Do you want to go again? Y for Yes, N for No.";
        cin >> repeat;


    } while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
    cout << "Program ending.\n";

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int *nums, int num_students)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_students; i++){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num_students; j++){
            if (nums[i] > nums[j])
{
                temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[j];
                nums[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}


double calculateMean(int *nums, int num_students)
{
    double total = 0;
    double average;

    for (int count = 0; count < num_students; count++)
    {
        total += nums[count];
    }
    average = total / num_students;
    return average;
}


double calculateMedian(int *nums, int num_students)
{
    double median = 0.0;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);


    if (num_students % 2 == 0)
    {
        median = (nums[num_students / 2 - 1] + nums[(num_students / 2)]) / 2.0;
    }
    else
        median = nums[num_students / 2];

    return median;
}


int calculateMode(int *nums, int num_students)
{
    int mode = 0;
    int val = 0;
    int index;


    for (index = 0; index < num_students - 1; index++)  // note the - 1 here
    {
        if (nums[index] == nums[index + 1])
        {
            mode++;
            val = *(nums + index);
        }
    }
    if (val > 0)
        return val;
    else
        return -1;

}
```

Comment: What is the question...?

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg It appears that my logic is flawed. I forgot to add that into the main post, but I'm just wondering if anyone can help me figure out why it's not working like it's supposed to.

Comment: A debugger would certainly assist in that goal.  You should probably note whether your input is sorted or not. If not, only the mean calculation looks to have hope of success. And `mode` calculation invokes undefined behavior, as `*(nums + (index + 1)` when `index == (num_students-1)` draws out of bounds on the array. Similar problem exists in `median` calculation. Remember C/C++ arrays are *zero* based.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm pretty sure I fixed it... How does that code look now? Although, I'm not 100% sure on how to output more than one mode. Any ideas for that? It works though, minus the mode part.

Answer (score 0):

One error that is in your `calculateMode` function:

```
for (index = 0; index < num_students; index++)
{
    if (*(nums + index) == *(nums + (index + 1)))  
                                           ^^^ // this goes out of bounds
```

Your loop accesses one beyond the last student on the last iteration.  It would be simpler to do two things:

1) Use array syntax and

2) Loop 1 less time

```
  for (index = 0; index < num_students - 1; index++)  // note the - 1 here
    {
        if (nums[index] == nums[index + 1])
```

---

For your `calculateMedian`, the error is that you will go out of bounds if the number of students is even.

For example, assume `num_students` is 2, thus your array has only two elements:

```
median = (nums[num_students / 2] + nums[(num_students / 2) + 1]) / 2.0;
```

is the same as

```
median = (nums[1] + nums[2]) / 2.0;  //nums[2] is out of bounds
```

The correction is to do this:

```
median = (nums[num_students / 2 - 1 ] + nums[(num_students / 2 )]) / 2.0;
```

Comment: This seems to help, however, the answers I'm getting are still wrong. If I say there's 7 students, then do 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 10 for the input, I get the average is 31.4(correct), the median is 30(incorrect), and the mode is 10(correct). It seems as though it's being converted into human counting(humans start counting at 1, computers at 0), and then messing up...

Comment: Please change your `calculateMedian` function to also respect the boundary conditions.  In addition, the numbers have to be sorted to be used in a median calculation.

Comment: How exactly would I change that? Also, I did add a bubble sort function, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/qhKi78zq

Comment: I updated the answer to show what is wrong with your `calculateMedian`.  As to your code from the link, your `bubbleSort` function `return` statement -- what is that supposed to do?   Also, you should update your question with this bubble sort code, as others may not be able to reach a URL link due to restrictions and won't be permanent.

Comment: Thank you, and VS13 says that it needs a return statement if it's not there, so that's why I have it. I'm going to update it now also. But, lets say that there are 7 students, and no numbers are the same. The mode will output -1, which is obviously wrong. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Your `bubbleSort` function should have a `void` return.  Also, your `return` statement isn't doing what you think it's doing.  Might as well get rid of it and just have the function a `void` function.  As to the mode, you do know that you can more than 1 mode, right?  Your code didn't take that in consideration.  http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Mode-of-a-Set-of-Numbers

Comment: Ok, I changed it to a void. As far as the mode, how would I even make it accept more than one? Vectors, more variables? I'm kind of drawing a blank on that part...

Comment: @3ncrypt3d Well, if this is homework, maybe the idea is to have you figure out how to design a function that collates one or more modes.  If it is homework, and there are not supposed to be duplicates, then make sure that these are the requirements (then your code will work).

Comment: It's not homework, just from a c++ book that I've borrowed from a friend. I'm not exactly sure if it's supposed to just collect one mode, or more. I'd rather go with the latter, because more is usually better.

Comment: Well, make usage of `std::map<int, int>` to count the number of occurrences of each number (the key is the number, the data is the count for that number).  Then take the generated map and use it to get the numbers that are tied with the highest count value.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at my program.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void fill_array(long int a[],long int size);
double mean(long int a[],double& sum,long int size);
double median(long int a[],long int size);
void bubble_sort(long int a[],long int size);
int mode(long int a[],long int size);

int main()
{
    long int size;
    cin >> size;
    long int a[size];
    double sum = 0.0,mn1,mn2,mn3;
    fill_array(a,size);
    mn1 = mean(a,sum,size);
    mn2 = median(a,size);
    mn3 = mode(a,size);
    cout << mn1 << endl;
    cout << mn2 << endl;
    cout << mn3;
    return 0;
}
void fill_array(long int a[],long int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}
double mean(long int a[],double& sum,long int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    double mn;
    mn = sum/size;
    return mn;
}
double median(long int a[],long int size)
{
    bubble_sort(a,size);
    double md;
    if(size%2==0)
    {
        md = (a[size/2]+a[(size/2)-1])/2.0;
    }
    else
    {
        md = a[size/2];
    }
    return md;
}
void bubble_sort(long int a[],long int size)
{
    for(int i=size-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                int temp = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int mode(long int a[],long int size)
{
    int mode=a[0], mx=1, count=1;
    for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]) {
            ++count;
        }
        else
            count=1;
        if(count>mx)
        {
            mx=count;
            mode=a[i];
        }
    }
    return mode;
}
```